# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended in pyspark expression

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00933

i cant understand what is wrong with this query. Someone can explain to me where is the error. Thank you so much

```
SELECT
  WF1.GUID,
  WF1.COD_FONTE,
  WF1.NOME_FILE,
  VW.COD_STEP_PRECEDENTE,
  VW.COD_STEP_ATTUALE AS WF1
FROM
  MONITOR.FILE_WORKFLOW
  INNER JOIN MONITOR.VW_JOB_FONTE_STEP AS VW ON WF1.COD_FONTE = VW.COD_FONTE
  AND VW.JOB_KEY = 'FLATTENER'
WHERE
  WF1.GUID = '5f58d00b6102ab20a8d5c83f'
  AND WF1.ESITO = 'OK'
  AND WF1.COD_STEP = VW.COD_STEP_PRECEDENTE
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      MONITOR.FILE_WORKFLOW AS WF2
    WHERE
      WF2.GUID = '5f58d00b6102ab20'
      AND WF2.ESITO = 'OK'
      AND WF2.COD_STEP = VW.COD_STEP_ATTUALE
      AND WF1.IDE_FILE_WORKFLOW_PARENT = WF2.IDE_FILE_WORKFLOW_PARENT
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you're using the table alias wrong

```
VW.COD_STEP_ATTUALE AS WF1 <-- WF1 is a column alias 
FROM
MONITOR.FILE_WORKFLOW
                                              
INNER JOIN MONITOR.VW_JOB_FONTE_STEP AS VW 
  ON WF1.COD_FONTE = VW.COD_FONTE <-- here you are using WF1 as a table alias
```

I assume this will fix the problem

```
VW.COD_STEP_ATTUALE
FROM
MONITOR.FILE_WORKFLOW WF1 <-- alias name goes here
```

Comment: Neither of the table aliases should have "AS" - Oracle allows that for column aliases but *not* for table aliases.

Comment: @AlexPoole you're right, thanks! Just copied that over with no attention to details

Comment: i removed all AS but still got an error : cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: @FracescoSciarra check if table names are correct and whether user has access to it. Login as that user and try to select from both MONITOR.VW_JOB_FONTE_STEP and MONITOR.FILE_WORKFLOW

Comment: @FracescoSciarra - you still need to move the WF1 alias from the column to the table, as this answer shows; unclear if you've done that.